# Can a pair of pointers to different functions taking different types of parameters be compatible?

Tags: c, function-pointers, language-lawyer, undefined-behavior

Can we put a function address of a particular signature into a function pointer which is defined to have some other signature and use it seamlessly?

For example, the following code

```
#include <stdio.h>

void print_n(int *pn) {
    printf("%d\n", *pn);
}

void print_n_wrapper(void *p) {
    print_n(p);
}

int main(void) {
    int n = 123;
    void (*f)(void *) = print_n_wrapper;
    f(&n);
    f = print_n;
    f(&n);
    return 0;
}
```

gets compiled and runs fine in my machine. Am I invoking undefined behavior somehow?

Comment: Yes you are invoking UB. Those pointer types are not compatible.

Comment: It work find, but compiler tells you`warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, it is [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Quoting `C11`, chapter §6.3.2.3, *Pointers*, (*emphasis mine*)

> A pointer to a function of one type may be converted to a pointer to a function of another
>   type and back again; the result shall compare equal to the original pointer. **If a converted
>   pointer is used to call a function whose type is not compatible with the referenced type,
>   the behavior is undefined.**

and regarding the "function whose type is not compatible" part, the definition of compatibility goes like

> For two function types to be compatible, both shall specify compatible return types.<sup>(146)</sup>
>   Moreover, the parameter type lists, if both are present, shall agree in the number of
>   parameters and in use of the ellipsis terminator; corresponding parameters shall have
>   compatible types.

That means, `void *` and `int *` *should have been* the same types, but they **are not**. So, the functions are also not of compatible type.

Comment: OP is asking whether his two different function types are *compatible* , so your answer should go into what it means for function types to be compatible

Answer (score 6):

The call to `print_n(p)` in `print_n_wrapper` *is* defined since all you're doing is converting a `void*` which was originally an `int*` to an `int*`

The assignment `f = print_n;` will give you trouble. Although the assignment **is** defined, the behaviour on the subsequent call `f(&n)` **is** undefined.